# Formatting arrays in corelation to ther arrays C

Tags: arrays, c, function, sorting, formatting

I am trying to make a function that is able to recognize if `Winning_order` arrays integers are within `Order1,Order2,Order3`. In `Order1` the first row of `Winning_order` is present `{1,2,3}` as well as in `order2`. However in `Order3` none of the elements correlate to the values of `Winning_order` so it is not a valid output.

```
int main(void)
{
  int Order1[5] = {1,2,3}
  int Order2[5] = {1,2,5,3}
  int Order3[5] = {1,2,5}
  int Winning_order[5][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9},{1,5,9},{3,5,7}};
  
  return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Order1
Order2
```

Comment: You should start with a function to compare 2 arrays, then a search function that looks for one array in `Winning_order`, then you use a loop to repeat this step for `Order1`, `Order2`, `Order3`

Comment: By the way, that code doesn't compile, the dimensions of `Winning_order` are wrong, and the expected output too

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jack Lilhammers's comment, you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int match_arrays(int *arr1, int *arr2, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  int Order1[3] = {1,2,3};
  int Order2[4] = {1,2,5,3};
  int Order3[3] = {1,2,5};
  int Winning_order[8][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9},{1,5,9},{3,5,7}};

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (match_arrays(Order1, Winning_order[i], 3)) {
      printf("Order1");
    }
    if (match_arrays(Order2, Winning_order[i], 3)) {
      printf("Order2");
    }
    if (match_arrays(Order3, Winning_order[i], 3)) {
      printf("Order3");
    }
  }

  
  return 0;
}
```

Be cause those are statically declared arrays, you have to use a series of if statements, or create a new array out of them, and it forces a lot to be hard coded.

EDIT: fixed include, dimensions, removed breaks, fixed function calls

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as @Jack Lilhammers pointed out, your expected output is incorrect if we can assume we understand what you are trying to accomplish: Your problem is essentially to check if an array is an element of an array-of-arrays.

This can be achieved like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_array_element(int rows, int columns, int arr1[rows][columns],
                     int arr2[columns]) {

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if(arr1[i][j] != arr2[j]) {
                break;
            }
            if(j == columns - 1) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {

    /* as Order1 and Order3 have been declared as 5-arrays but are only
    initialized with 3 integers, the remaining two elements are zero and
    can (should) be ignored */
    int Order1[5] = {1, 2, 3};
    /* not clear how you wish to compare a 4-array with a 3-array and so
    the code will clip the last element */
    int Order2[5] = {1, 2, 5, 3};
    int Order3[5] = {1, 2, 5};

    int Winning_order[8][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9},
                                {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9},
                                {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}
                              };
    
    if(is_array_element(8, 3, Winning_order, Order1)) {
        printf("Order1\n");  
    }
    if(is_array_element(8, 3, Winning_order, Order2)) {
        printf("Order2\n");  
    }
    if(is_array_element(8, 3, Winning_order, Order3)) {
        printf("Order3\n");  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output we get is:

```
Order1
```

Comment: Thank you for the code however, I am trying to get `Order1` and `Order2`

Comment: @ege Selcuk Your original post is unclear however I believe I understand what you are trying to do: You are trying to check if the elements in any one array of ```Winning_order``` are in the integer arrays of ```Order1```, ```Order2```, or ```Order3```. Is this correct?

Comment: I am trying to see if any of the 3 column values of each row are within the `Order1, Order2,` or ` Order3`. So in this case `Order1` and `Order2` would be true. Sorry for the late reply.